# Slice array to seq with no copy

Tags: arrays, scala, seq

I'm trying to get a slice of an `Array` as `Seq` avoiding copy. I can make use of `toSeq` method.

```
val array = Array[AnyRef](
  new Integer(1), 
  new Integer(2), 
  new Integer(3), 
  new Integer(4), 
  new Integer(5)
)
val seq = array.toSeq
array(1) = null
println(seq.mkString(",")) //1,null,3,4,5
```

It works fine: [Ideone Live example](https://ideone.com/Bza0CV). The array was not copied. But when I try to slice it

```
val array = Array[AnyRef](
  new Integer(1),
  new Integer(2),
  new Integer(3),
  new Integer(4),
  new Integer(5)
)
val seq = array.toSeq.slice(0, 3)
array(1) = null
println(seq.mkString(",")) //1,2,3
```

As can be seen the copy is made: [Ideone Live Example](https://ideone.com/ldiaX0). I am trying to avoid it. Is there a way to do so in Scala?

Comment: `slice` as well as many other methods on the standard library will return a modified copy while leaving the original unmodified. Why don't you want to create a copy? If the array is too big, you can create your own wrapper that will forward calls to the underlying collection - Also, you do not need to call `toSeq` since an **Array** is a **Seq**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I found a way to do this via `JavaConverters` as `util.Arrays.asList(array: _*).subList(1, 4).asScala` but this looks pretty ugly....

Comment: Well if you really need to deal with arrays in such a low level, you will end using **Java** and writing code that looks like **Java**, since the **Scala** _standard library_ is not optimized for those cases, but that is not bad, that is the beauty of **Scala**, it lets you chose how you want to program. - Anyways, I insist, are you sure you really need that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
val a = (0 to 10).toArray
val b = a.toSeq.view.slice(1, 9)
a(5) = 12345
b.mkString(",") // res5: String = 1,2,3,4,12345,6,7,8
```

And here is a [quote from Jurassic Park](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nazm3_OXac):

> "Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they *could* that they didn't stop to think if they *should*."

Comment: I just recall that you can just  `val b = a.view(1, 9)`.